# SyntaxError when using const and arrow function inside a class

Tags: javascript, class

I'm working through some CodeWars katas and I would like to know: For what reason does this syntax work...

```
class SmallestIntegerFinder {
  findSmallestInt(args) {
    return Math.min(...args)
  }
}
```

...but this other does not?

```
class SmallestIntegerFinder {
  const findSmallestInt = args => Math.min(...args)
}
```

This is the error trace printed:

```
const findSmallestInt = args => Math.min(...args)
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at 
    at evalScript (bootstrap_node.js:353:27)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:122:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:121:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

I haven't had any problem using the second syntax in other katas, but this is the first time I use it inside a class, so I guess it has something to do with JavaScript classes that I haven't learnt yet or something else that is escaping me at the moment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ES6 does not support fields in class literals.

Comment: Because a `class` body is not a block that could hold arbitrary statements?

Comment: Would you have expected `const … = …` to work inside an object literal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because that's not valid syntax. Within a class, you do not use variable bindings like `const`, `let`, or `var` to define members. The syntax is nice and simple.

There is a proposal, however, that will allow [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), similar to your second example. However, you would still not use `const`, `let`, or `var` to define these either.

Edited: thanks @Bergi for pointing out that class/instance method syntax isn't sugar for anything, that's just how you define methods.

Comment: Actually, the method definition syntax is not a shorthand for anything, it's the only valid syntax inside a `class` body. Notice that in contrast to object literals, there are no commata either.

Comment: Thank you all! I guess my error was considering that functions and class methods could use the same syntax